# Función ordinal: pasa caracter y devuelve posición

Tags: c

No logro realizar el siguiente ejercicio:

**Escribir una función que reciba por parámetro una frase en español en un vector de char y cifre dicha frase en código Morse.**

Vectores que contienen los códigos morse correspondientes a cada letra:

codigo[1]={'.','-'};

codigo[2]={'-','.','.','.'};

codigo[3]={'-','.','-','.'};

codigo[4]={'-','.','.'};

codigo[5]={'.'};

codigo1 corresponde a A, codigo2 corresponde a B y así sucesivamente.
**Cómo hacer una función ordinal, que pasándole un carácter, me devuelva la posición?**
Ejemplo:
ordinal('A')=1

Alguien lo sabe hacer????

Comment: ¿Qué has probado y qué problemas te has encontrado? Te podemos ayudar con alguna duda que tengas al escribir tú el programa, pero escribir el programa por tí es off-topic.

Comment: No quiero que escriban el programa. Lo que no sé hacer es cómo asociar la letra A al código 1. Si fuera por el código ascii sería más fácil.

Comment: Un char se puede pasar a ASCII con solo hacer un `cast` a `int` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322056/how-to-convert-an-ascii-character-into-an-int-in-c. Y si sabes que `A` en ASCII es `65` y su ordinal es `1`, entonces la diferencia entre el ordinal y el ASCII es una simple resta. Hay que tener cuidado con mayúsculas y minúsculas, y con caracteres especiales como `ñ`, espacio en blanco, etc.

Comment: Puede ser un vector/array bidimensional (primer índice corresponde a la letra, segundo índice corresponde a los distintos símbolos morse) o un vector/array de struts

Comment: Pongo así y me da error: char codigo [26][2];
char [26][2] codigo = new int [][];
codigo[1] = new char[2] {'.','-'};
codigo[2]= new char[4] {'-','.','.','.'};

Answer (score 0):

> No quiero que escriban el programa. Lo que no sé hacer es cómo asociar la letra A al código 1.

Suponiendo que no existen números así como tampoco signos de puntuación ni diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas

```
char letra = /* ... */

int indice = letra - 'a'; // Si la letra es minúscula
int indice = letra - 'A'; // Si la letra es mayúscula
```

Así, a la `a` le corresponderá el índice 0, a la `b` el 1 y así hasta la `z`.

Ya solo tendrías que elaborar la matriz correspondiente:

```
char *matriz[] = { ".-", "-...", "-.-.", ... };
```